# How to disable a search filter of a listview in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

How to disable a search filter of a listview in jquery mobile.

My Code:

```
ul(data-role='listview' ,data-filter="false")
                  li
                    a(href="JavaScript:editGroupFormSubmission('#{groupsId[0]}')") 
                         p A
                  li
                    a(href="/mfi/api/1.0/client/ci/kycuploading") 
                       p B
                  li
                    a(href="/mfi/api/1.0/client/ci/groups/fieldverification") 
                         p C
                  li
                    a(href="/mfi/api/1.0/client/ci/groups/cca1") 
                         p D
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with javascript `$('.ui-listview-filter input').textinput('disable');`.

Answer (score 0):

```
.nav-search .ui-bar-a { visibility:hidden !important;}
```

Comment: Care to comment your code? How does it works? How does it answers the OP question?